# ng-pluralize "when" bound to a variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

All the Angular examples I've seen demonstrate ng-pluralize with a literal "when" parameter:

```
<ng-pluralize count="x" when="{'one': 'thing', 'other': 'things'}"></ng-pluralize>
```

Is it possible to use a scope variable as the when attribute?  For instance:

```
<ng-pluralize count="x" when="things"></ng-pluralize>
```

where `$scope.things` is set to `{'one': 'thing', 'other': 'things'}`

I've tried it and it doesn't work as I've specified it here, but I'm hoping I'm just missing something and it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for ng-pluralize](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPluralize) it shows that "count" is either a string or an expression but "when" is just a string. I would guess then that this isn't possible. I will write a plunker in a moment to test but the documentation seems pretty clear. Maybe a feature request is in order? : )

**Plunker** - As promised, you can [use this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1bDAkjSrsmPags4UEbvz?p=preview) to see the string version working, but no matter how you change it the equivalent version that uses a variable won't work!

Comment: Thanks!  I missed that little "expression" tag in the documentation, but you're right - it's got its own evaluation going on.  Too bad!

Answer (score 4):

So I just found that, while you can't effectively put a variable in the `when` attribute (you can, but updates aren't reflected), you can do this:

```
<ng-pluralize count="modalUsers.length" 
  when="{ 'one': '{{ templateConfig.pluralizeConfig.one }}',
          'other': '{{ templateConfig.pluralizeConfig.other }}' }">
</ng-pluralize>
```

And then update the templateConfig object.